# How do I automatically filter out objects in a query set if a field in an object is set to true in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model like so...

```
class Driver(SupremeModel):
    name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Cars.Car', null=False, blank=False)
```

This model inherits from this abstract model...

```
class SupremeModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_creator", null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then I have a ModelForm like so...

```
class DriverForm(SupremeModelForm):
    class Meta(SupremeModelForm.Meta):
        model = Driver
```

DriverForm inherits from this SupremeModelForm...

```
class SupremeModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['created', 'creator', 'deleted', 'modified']
```

I want to make it so anytime anything that inherits from SupremeModel is queried for data, it automatically excludes all the data where deleted=True...

In this case, so that when I render the DriverModelForm, deleted entries of car are not displayed...

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

After some more research I discovered the solution is to override the default model manager of the abstract model... Like so...

```
class SupremeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SupremeManager, self).get_queryset().filter(deleted=False)

class SupremeModel(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_creator", null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)

    objects = SupremeManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Make sure you provide a non-filtered manager as well, otherwise there's no way to access the deleted objects at all.